# How to make fish shell use an rvm ruby by default

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, fish

I'm using fish shell 2.10 on Mac OS X 10.9.1. I would like to use a Ruby that I have installed using RVM as the default in my terminals, however I can't seem to make this work.

I've tried `rvm use 2.1.0 --default` but upon opening a new terminal I still get the following:

```
> which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

Running the `rvm` command causes the ruby to be loaded:

```
> which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
> rvm
[...]
> which ruby
/Users/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby
```

But it's annoying to have to do this every time I open a new terminal.

Comment: have you installed ruby 2.1.0 with rvm?

Comment: Yes, I have. Though the same thing happens when trying to set other installed Rubies as default as well.

Comment: issue: `/usr/bin/ruby -v`, and please look at the `.bash_profile`, to see the line: `source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`

Comment: As stated in the question I'm using fish shell so I don't think changes to my `.bash_profile` will make any difference?

Comment: ok, so have to add to .fish's init script call to `rvm` that changes the required ruby to default. But in fish does the `rvm` works?

Comment: I have started working on official support in this ticket https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2516 - it should load default ruby but does not have cd handler, if it works and you need cd handler open a new ticket requesting it

Comment: Not really helping your specific issue. But if you are not using any of the specific features in rvm, like `gemsets` you could go for something simpler. When I first switched to fish I wondered why all the solutions were so complicated, when it is just about setting a path. So I rolled my own: https://github.com/terlar/fry

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Firstly install rvm fish functions from [rvm.io](http://rvm.io/integration/fish)

```
curl -L --create-dirs -o ~/.config/fish/functions/rvm.fish https://raw.github.com/lunks/fish-nuggets/master/functions/rvm.fish
```

You should now be able to use rvm command in fish after reopening terminal.

Run the following to add the line `rvm default` to your fish config file.

```
echo 'rvm default' >> ~/.config/fish/config.fish
```

You should now be able to use ruby related binaries and gems after reopening terminal.

Comment: When I add that last command to my config file, every time I open a new terminal the line `rvm default` gets added to the config file, and each new terminal opened takes longer and longer to load.

Comment: @CalamityAdam I changed the wording in the answer. You should run the line with echo once not append it to `config.fish`.

Answer (score 7):

I think to make it easier, you can add a [rvm] [2](https://github.com/fisherman/rvm) plugin to fish shell via [fisher] [1](https://github.com/jorgebucaran/fisher).

For install fisher:

```
curl -Lo ~/.config/fish/functions/fisher.fish --create-dirs git.io/fisher
```

After, install rvm plugin for Fish Shell:

```
fisher add jorgebucaran/fish-nvm
```

or

```
fisher install oh-my-fish/plugin-rvm
```

After that, rvm runs perfect.

(was `fisher rvm` previously)

Comment: I had more success using https://github.com/oh-my-fish/plugin-rvm

If you use fisher: `fisher install oh-my-fish/plugin-rvm` works

Answer (score 5):

Install [oh-my-fish](https://github.com/oh-my-fish/oh-my-fish) very useful tools, have rvm plugin and many cool another.

> Framework for managing your fish shell configuration

Comment: I have installed this (and enabled the RVM plugin) but am unsure how to get it to load my RVM Ruby by default. Currently the behaviour is the same as described in my question.

Comment: this plugin provide ruby environment manager, i have same problem and use this solution. Apparently something wrong on you config or path variable

Comment: That project seems abandoned. Use fisherman instead https://github.com/fisherman/fisherman

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because, out of the box, the Rubies installed through RVM aren't added to your path. When you run any RVM command, it adds the paths relative to the ruby version you're using to $PATH. RVM seems to take care of bash and zsh but doesn't have built-in support for correcting the paths for your dot files.

Here's an example of my path before an RVM command:

```
/Users/grant/pear/bin /usr/local/sbin/ /Users/grant/.rvm/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/git/bin /usr/local/go/bin
```

Here's an example of my path after running 'rvm':

```
/Users/grant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin /Users/grant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/bin /Users/grant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin /Users/grant/pear/bin /usr/local/sbin/ /Users/grant/.rvm/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/git/bin /usr/local/go/bin
```

The bottom line is that you'll want to add the .rvm files to your path depending on the version you default to. [This post](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/527) helped me figure out how to do that. You can append the paths that RVM adds to your fish profile with:

```
set -g -x PATH $PATH <paths_to_add>
```

Example from above:

```
set -g -x PATH $PATH /Users/grant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin /Users/grant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/bin /Users/grant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin
```

To have this run every time you load fish, add the above command to ~/.config/fish/config.fish. Alternatively, you can add the rvm command to your fish config and have it load it for you.

Hope this helps!
-Grant

Answer (score 0):

This below worked for me from the fish google group forum.
credit eggegg for this solution below:

The original support for fish shell requires converting bash script to a fish script.
As it mentioned here: https://rvm.io/integration/fish.

I found there's a simpler solution: let bash do the bash scripts, we only need the result of the environment variables.

Code:
https://gist.github.com/eggegg/6077153

Just insert the first one into your own config.fish, then copy rvm.fish to ~/.config/fish/functions/ will do the tricks.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 0):

In your config.fish load rvm plugin and call it silently:

`. ~/oh-my-fish/plugins/rvm/rvm
rvm >/dev/null`

If you're using bob-the-fish theme you'll have a ruby version in your prompt like this:

`ruby-2.1.2 > ~/d/web > master >`

Which can be suppressed, if you'd like, by removing the line below in bobthefish/fish_prompt.fish:

`__bobthefish_prompt_rubies`