# RVM using wrong ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I had problems with ruby and in the process of fixing it I installed a newer version. However, when I open up a terminal window and type `ruby -v`, I get - `ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin13.2.0]`

This version is corrupt (e.g. I can't run rails s)

If I run this command: `rvm --default use ruby-2.1.4`, then everything is right in the world and I'm good... until I open a new terminal window.

Can someone help me understand where I set my default version to 2.1.4?

Comment: yes that worked, but I was looking to understand at a system level why it was happening so I could correct the root cause

Comment: I thought the problem was not fixed and you didn't ask for any explanation! People are helping us for nothing, and we can at least let them know what's wrong with their solution and acknowledge the help if any. :)

Comment: actually this was answered for me here

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21334389/how-to-make-fish-shell-use-an-rvm-ruby-by-default][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21334389/how-to-make-fish-shell-use-an-rvm-ruby-by-default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem after a fresh install of my OS, selecting `Run command as a login shell` in my terminal solved the problem.

```
Terminal > 
Edit > 
Profile Preference > 
Title and Command > 
(Check) **Run command as a login shell**
Restart Terminal
```

> Login shells (typically when a terminal window is opened) will use `.bash_profile` but interactive, non-login shells reference `.bashrc` (likely where the rvm shell code are loaded).