# issue with install rvm and fish shell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, shell, fish

I wanna install rvm on my machine via this line

`curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

After that I install rvm plugin on fish shell (fisher rvm) now when I run

```
rvm | head -n 1
```

To see rvm version in terminal, here the result:

```
The file /Applications/PhpStorm.app does not exist.
/var/folders/89/03x00qyx4q9fps00mz9bns840000gn/T/rvm.fish.XXXXXXXXXX.skskZ4L6: line 1: rvm: command not found
```

Comment: "/Applications" -- is this OSX?

Comment: @glennjackman yes it is

Comment: I found this question helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21334389/how-to-make-fish-shell-use-an-rvm-ruby-by-default